# Keras Sequential to Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am new to deep learning and have been trying to convert the Keras sequential API to the functional API running on the CIFAR10 image dataset but have been having some difficulty. I've converted the model which looks the same except for the input layer yet the sequential has an average accuracy of around ~70% and my functional has an average accuracy of around ~10%. I would really appreciate some help with regards to figuring out what is going wrong. Here is my functional code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from keras import datasets, layers, models
from keras.models import Model, Input, Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Download and prepare:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0
input_shape = train_images[0,:,:,:].shape
```

Create model:

```
input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='valid')(input)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)

x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(10)(x)

model = Model(input, x, name='Functional')
```

Compile and train:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

[Here is a link to the original sequential CNN](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/images/cnn.ipynb) which is a google collaboratory notebook. I would really appreciate any help in trying to understand and fix what is going wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some issues with `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` loss.

Check this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38632

The following model gives good accuracy:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from keras import datasets, layers, models
from keras.models import Model, Input, Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0
train_labels, test_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels, 10) , tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(test_labels, 10)
input_shape = train_images[0,:,:,:].shape


input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='valid')(input)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)

x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(input, x, name='Functional')

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

```
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)           (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_11 (MaxPooling (None, 15, 15, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)           (None, 13, 13, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_12 (MaxPooling (None, 6, 6, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)           (None, 4, 4, 64)          36928     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 64)                65600     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 122,570
Trainable params: 122,570
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 50000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 15s 305us/step - loss: 1.4870 - accuracy: 0.4600 - val_loss: 1.2874 - val_accuracy: 0.5488
Epoch 2/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 15s 301us/step - loss: 1.1365 - accuracy: 0.5989 - val_loss: 1.0789 - val_accuracy: 0.6191
Epoch 3/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 15s 301us/step - loss: 0.9869 - accuracy: 0.6547 - val_loss: 0.9506 - val_accuracy: 0.6700
Epoch 4/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 15s 301us/step - loss: 0.8896 - accuracy: 0.6907 - val_loss: 0.9509 - val_accuracy: 0.6695
Epoch 5/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 16s 311us/step - loss: 0.8135 - accuracy: 0.7151 - val_loss: 0.8688 - val_accuracy: 0.7046
Epoch 6/10
50000/50000 [==============================] - 15s 303us/step - loss: 0.7566 - accuracy: 0.7351 - val_loss: 0.8411 - val_accuracy: 0.7141
```